# Getting the wrong type when using a function imported from C in Python - Ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I wanted to use a function written in C which maps a number from one range to another:

```
//mapping a number <value> from 0 -> <max>  to 
//<wanted_min> -> <wanted_max>

float map3(float value, float max, float wanted_min, float wanted_max) {
    return (( (value/max) * (wanted_max - wanted_min) ) + wanted_min);
}
```

which outputs the wanted result (-0.8 in this case) when I run it in C (in Visual Studio).

but when I run it in python (with the module ctypes):

```
from ctypes import *
c_funcs = CDLL("./myf.so")

def map_num(value, Max, wanted_min, wanted_max):

    x = c_funcs.map3(ctypes.c_float(value), ctypes.c_float(Max),
                     ctypes.c_float(wanted_min), ctypes.c_float(wanted_max))
    print(type(x))
    return x

print(map_num(10,  100, -1, 1))
```

output:

```
<class 'int'>
4
```

the type of x is int, and I can't figure out why.

and if I use regular python I get the wanted result (of course):

```
def map_num(value, Max, wanted_min, wanted_max):
    return (((value  / Max ) * (wanted_max - wanted_min)) + wanted_min)

print(map_num(10,  100, -1, 1))
```

I get the wanted result which is -0.8 (for example in this case)

I'm sorry for the lack of PEP8, any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Probably, a duplicate of [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't apply a prototype to function, ctypes assumes that arguments and return are int. See [Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes). You can prototype your function so that nothing needs to be recast.

```
from ctypes import *
c_funcs = CDLL("./myf.so")

c_funcs.map3.argtypes = [c_float, c_float, c_float, c_float]
c_funcs.map3.restype = c_float

def map_num(value, Max, wanted_min, wanted_max):

    x = c_funcs.map3(value, Max, wanted_min, wanted_max)
    print(type(x))
    return x

print(map_num(10,  100, -1, 1))
```

Now that `map3` has been fully prototyped, there isn't a need for the intermediate `map_num` function if all it does is call the C function and return its result.

Comment: ahah - I hadn't spotted that the args are `int`-assumed too!

Comment: additionally / fwiw I'd just write simple functions like this in native Python (`min(max(value, _min), _max)`) or using NumPy (which may really be the intention; performing some fast operation over a vector) and prefer to [use a struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure) for more complex actions or access to some syscall (where the function returns `int` for success/failed and has some buffer field for the response)

Answer (score 1):

`ctypes` can't infer the return type here and assumes it to be `int`, so you need to set it explicitly

Just do this before you call the function

```py
    ...
    c_funcs.map3.restype = c_float
    c_funcs.map3(...)
```

From the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types

> By default functions are assumed to return the C `int` type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.